# scrapy extract the url of image

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

how to fetch image url from website using scrapy in python.please help me.this is my code

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
#from scrapy.linkextractors.lxmlhtml import LxmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class MyItem(Item):
    url= Field()


class someSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'crawltest'
    allowed_domains = ['bambeeq.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.bambeeq.com/']
    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=()), callback='parse_obj', follow=True),)

    def parse_obj(self,response):
        item = MyItem()
        item['url'] = []
        for link in LinkExtractor(allow=(),deny = self.allowed_domains).extract_links(response):
            item['url'].append(link.url)
            #item['image'].append(link.img)
        return item
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 4):

You are extracting the links ('a' element), not the images ('img' element). Try this:

```
# iterate over the list of images
for image in response.xpath('//img/@src').extract():
    # make each one into a full URL and add to item[]
    item['url'].append(response.urljoin(image))

yield item
```